# Define environment variable based on target (build or upload)

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, platformio

On Visual Studio Code with PlatformIO when I click on **[v]** button (**PlatformIO:Build**) the IDE run following task:

```
> Executing task: C:\Users\Mary\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run <

Processing d1_mini (platform: espressif8266; board: d1_mini; framework: arduino)
...
...
```

when I click on **[=>]** button (**PlatformIO:Upload**) the IDE run following task:

```
> Executing task: ~\.platformio\penv\Scripts\platformio.exe run --target upload <

Processing d1_mini (platform: espressif8266; board: d1_mini; framework: arduino)
...
...
```

Explanation:

> https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/userguide/cmd_run.html

I need to discriminate when the target is **run** (compile) or target is **upload** (--target upload) for setting different environmental variable. Something like

```
[env:specific_defines]
build_flags =
  -D MY_VAR=true
```

because when i compile the project i don't want debug information (for example Serial.println()) that i want when i upload the program via usb with board attached.

I look [Build options](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_env_build.html) and [Advanced Scripting](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/advanced_scripting.html) but i don't find anything that was right for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer:
Build flags do not apply to UPLOAD - because at this time the sources are already built.

If you have two environments, say production and debug, you also have to upload variants.

```sh
pio run -e prod -> compiles prod environment
pio run -e prod -t upload -> uploads prod environment

pio run -e debug -> compiles debug environment
pio run -e debug -t upload -> uploads debug environment
```